# javascript change button value on confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this JS Code:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var res = confirm('You are about to add this Ticket Update with the following:\n\n' + $("textarea[name='ticket_update']").val() + '\n\n' + 'Time Start: ' + $("input[name='timestart_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timestart_time']").val() + '\n' + 'Time End: ' + $("input[name='timeend_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timeend_time']").val());
    if(!res) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
```

which shows a popup box with form submitted data and if you click OK it will submit the form, otherwise cancel and go back to the form.

I want to be able to make it so: if OK is clicked on the confirm box, the form button will be disabled and the text value will change. Then the form will submit as normal

Comment: I see a `$` here, can we assume jQuery? If so, can you tag it additionally as `jQuery` ?

Comment: This is JQuery syntax indeed.

Comment: Thank you - not thinking this morning :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if you are using `Jquery1.6` or higher version

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var res = confirm('You are about to add this Ticket Update with the following:\n\n' + $("textarea[name='ticket_update']").val() + '\n\n' + 'Time Start: ' + $("input[name='timestart_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timestart_time']").val() + '\n' + 'Time End: ' + $("input[name='timeend_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timeend_time']").val());
    if(!res) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#submit").val("my new button label");
        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
```

[Prop Reference](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var res = confirm('You are about to add this Ticket Update with the following:\n\n' + $("textarea[name='ticket_update']").val() + '\n\n' + 'Time Start: ' + $("input[name='timestart_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timestart_time']").val() + '\n' + 'Time End: ' + $("input[name='timeend_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timeend_time']").val());
    if(!res) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $("#submit").val("my new button label");
        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
```

If not, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If it's a submit button inside a form you need to prevent default to stop the page refreshing, see my answer

Comment: i have copied your answer and the form doesnt submit

Comment: any ideas why its not submitting?

Comment: maybe move the call to submit() to the top, and then disable the button afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little code snippet:

http://jsfiddle.net/XE2f6/

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
var res = confirm('You are about to add this Ticket Update with the following:\n\n' + $("textarea[name='ticket_update']").val() + '\n\n' + 'Time Start: ' + $("input[name='timestart_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timestart_time']").val() + '\n' + 'Time End: ' + $("input[name='timeend_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timeend_time']").val());
if(!res) {
    return false;
}
else {
    $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#submit").val("Sending");
    $("#ticket_update").submit();
}
```

});

$('#ticket_update').submit(function () {
    confirm("Put your submit stuff here");
});

1. Ask for confirmation
2. Disable the button
3. Change button value
4. Trigger submit event on the form
5. Catch triggered submit event on the form

---

Your form was in wrong format, you had to switch the double quotes for single ones, and single ones for doubles.

```
<form method="post" action="reviewtickets_history.php?seq=".$_GET['get']."&type=".$_GET['type']."#bo‌ttom" id="ticket_update">
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send!" /></form>
```

Comment: this isnt submitting the form either

Comment: check JS fiddle, it submits there. Also, copy the code from JSFiddle instead, it seems like its not copying all the code into stackoverflow.

Comment: what is the second confirm box for - Put your submit stuff here

Comment: form still not submitting - <form method="post" action="reviewtickets_history.php?seq='.$_GET["seq"].'&type='.$_GET["type"].'#bottom" id="ticket_update"> with your jsFiddle code

Comment: About the second confirm box, its there to check if the actual submit form is triggered. Since you're using PHP, i dont think you'll need it.

Comment: i have made the form action just rewivewtickets_history.php and its still not submitting

Comment: even if the form looks like <form method="post" action="reviewtickets_history.php" id="ticket_update"> its not submitting

Comment: Could you give me your entire submit form please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    var res = confirm('You are about to add this Ticket Update with the following:\n\n' + $("textarea[name='ticket_update']").val() + '\n\n' + 'Time Start: ' +   $("input[name='timestart_date']").val() + ' ' + $("input[name='timestart_time']").val() + '\n' + 'Time End: ' + $("input[name='timeend_date']").val() + ' ' +    $("input[name='timeend_time']").val());
    if(!res) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $("#ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

or jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
  //enter code here
}
```